# Siphon Incoming call issue when the app is in Background

Tags: ios, pjsip

We have been working on a voip application based on SIP. Siphon iOS project is being used.    We have been facing an issue with incoming call when the app is in Background. We have tried with the app in the required background modes : App provides Voice over IP services mode. and App plays audio or stream audio/video using Airplay modes. But it doesn't seem to work. So, would it be possible to receive the incoming calls even in the background? We have downloaded the code and compiled as per the instructions given in the pointer below:

http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Incoming calls in iOS background mode/state are allowed when using TCP only.

Since iOS 4.3 UDP is not supported when the App is in background. This is most probably your problem. You should try to configure a TCP connection in your SIP client (PJSIP has support for that) and your server needs to support TCP connection as well.

Example:

```
pjsua_transport_config_default(&(app_config->tcp_cfg));
app_config->tcp_cfg.port = val; /*Local Port*/
...
/* Add TCP transport */
status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP,
                                &app_config->tcp_cfg, NULL);
```

You need to add the TCP parameter to your SIP server (proxy) as well:

```
sip:example.com;transport=tcp;
```

For more details see:

[PJSIP - Using SIP TCP Transport](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Using_SIP_TCP)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will configure it with TCP and test it. But, we have iOS 7 now. So, any support for UDP when the App is in background?